# Hosting web page with nginx inside docker-compose: Can't resolve hostname

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, docker-compose

My setup is the following:

1. Backend: Flask server running on port 5000; implemented in python
2. Frontend: React app sending http-requests to backend
3. Both are dockerized and running on the same node using docker-compose

My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    image: <backend-image>

  frontend:
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - "backend:backend-python"
    image: <frontend-image>
```

The nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;                 
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

From the frontend I send requests to `http://backend-python:5000/<my-endpoint>`. `backend-python` is defined inside the frontend specification in docker-compose as hostname of the backend. When I run `docker-compose up` locally and open `localhost` in a browser the page gets displayed as expected. When I run `docker-compose up` on a Raspberry Pi 3 the frontend can't resolve `http://backend-python:5000/<my-endpoint>` when I open the page locally on my laptop.

I also tried to replace `nginx` with serving the build using `serve`. This leads to the same behaviour as described above.

From googling it seems to me that using docker-compose builds its own network in which each container can be found by its name or names defined under `links`.

Has anybody an idea why the name can't be resolved when accessing the page from an other machine?

Comment: This is my complete nginx config. I'm pretty new to nginx, so maybe adding proxys to the configuration might solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

A frontend app is running inside a browser and when the frontend app try to reach an API, it's the browser that try to communicate with it.

When you host a frontend app inside docker with nginx, all the container do is to server the static file needed by the browser, but it's not nginx that try to communicate with your API.

It's why your browser can't accès to your backend using the container name, you need to expose your API and change the API/backend URL in your frontend app to use `http://localhost:5000`.

Comment: Wouldn't that lead to the frontend trying to access the API on my machine instead of the raspberry?

Comment: So to make sure to access the API running inside the container i would need to call the API in the frontend using the IP of my raspberry?

Comment: Yes, if docker is running in an another host than your browser, you need to use the API host IP or dns name if you have one.